# Error al editar archivo XML usando un formulario en PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

Que tal, Estoy intentando editar un archivo .xml usando PHP y HTML, mi problema es que cuando edito un nodo va bien, entonces los demás nodos se eliminan y quedan vacíos. Aquí mi código completo.

Archivo libro1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<info>  
    <nombre>Paulo Coelho</nombre>
    <libro>El demonio y la señorita Prym</libro>
    <ano>2000</ano>
    <editorial>Planeta</editorial>
    <servidor>DropBox</servidor>
    <formato>.epub</formato>
</info>
```

y mi archivo editor.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 $data = simplexml_load_file('libros/libro1.xml');
 $data->nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
 $data->libro=$_POST['libro'];
 $data->año=$_POST['año'];
 $data->editorial=$_POST['editorial'];
 $data->servidor=$_POST['servidor'];
 $data->formato=$_POST['formato'];

$handle=fopen("libros/libro1.xml","wb");
fwrite($handle,$data->asXML());
fclose($handle);
}

$data=simplexml_load_file('libros/libro1.xml');
$info=$data->nombre;
$libro=$data->libro;
$año=$data->año;
$editorial=$data->editorial;
$servidor=$data->servidor;
$formato=$data->formato;

?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="nombre"> Escritor: <?php echo $info; ?>
<br>
<input type="text" name="libro"> Titulo del Libro: <?php echo $libro; ?>
<br>
<input type="text" name="año"> Año de Publicación: <?php echo $año; ?>
<br>
<input type="text" name="editorial"> Editorial: <?php echo $editorial; ?>
<br>
<input type="text" name="servidor"> Servidor: <?php echo $servidor; ?>
<br>
<input type="text" name="formato"> Formato: <?php echo $formato; ?>
<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Mi problema es que si edito el campo de formato agregando otro valor por ejemplo: .ebook entonces lo cambia, pero los demás nodos quedan vacíos.

Antes de editar el archivo libro1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<info>  
    <nombre>Paulo Coelho</nombre>
    <libro>El demonio y la señorita Prym</libro>
    <ano>2000</ano>
    <editorial>Planeta</editorial>
    <servidor>DropBox</servidor>
    <formato>.epub</formato>
</info>
```

Después de editar el archivo libro1.xml usando mi formulario:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<info>  
    <nombre></nombre>
    <libro></libro>
    <ano></ano>
    <editorial></editorial>
    <servidor></servidor>
    <formato>.ebook</formato>
</info>
```

solo queda editado el campo que he editado pero los demás desaparecen, Me podrían decir que estoy haciendo mal, Muchas gracias.

Comment: Estás sobrescribiendo cada vez que haces submit, no añadiendo.

Comment: ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo, me podrías echar una mano @Carmen?

Comment: Lo ideal sería que tu form guardara los datos de cada nodo como una tupla o fila en una tabla en una base de datos, y que luego consultaras la base de datos con los nodos que quieras para montar el xml. Si no, pasa los datos que ya tienes en inputs type=hidden y montas el xml primero con los datos de estos inputs y luego añades el nodo nuevo. Esto último si es un xml extenso puede ser pesado. También, aunque menos limpio y menos aconsejable, puedes guardar cada nodo en variables de sesión y consultarlas, para evitar pasarlas en el form.

Comment: Gracias por la información @Carmen, me podrías ayudar para poder hacerlo con la ultima opción, guardar cada nodo en una variable. Lo he intentando y creo que me ha ido peor. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo un ejemplo sencillo en el que se van guardando todos los valores ingresados en una variable de forma incremental, para ello hay que pasar dicha variable en el form.

Yo he hecho un `var_dump` del array para que veas que se van acumulando los valores, en tu caso lo que debes hacer es recorrer un array de valores e ir creando el nodo para cada elemento. Todos los arrays deben tener el mismo índice, es decir, si no rellenan un campo del formulario añades un elemento vacío en el correspondiente array. Esto implica la creación de [varios nodos](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_load_file.asp).

```
<?php
$nombres = array();
$libros = array();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $nombres = explode(",",$_POST['nombres']);
    $libros = explode(",",$_POST['libros']);
    array_push($nombres,$_POST['nombre']);
    array_push($libros,$_POST['libro']);

    var_dump($nombres); echo "<br>"; var_dump($libros); echo "<br><br>";
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="nombres" value="<?php echo implode(",",$nombres);?>">
<input type="hidden" name="libros" value="<?php echo implode(",",$libros);?>">
<label for="nombre">Escritor: </label>
<input type="text" name="nombre"> 
<br>
<label for="libro">Libro: </label>
<input type="text" name="libro">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Otra cosa, si quieres que los campos tengan un valor previo, por ejemplo el correspondiente al último nodo, en lugar de

```
<input type="text" name="nombre"> Escritor: <?php echo $info; ?>
```

hazlo con el atributo value:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $info; ?>">
```

y así el valor se envía en el formulario.

Ten en cuenta que este sistema sólo guardará la información mientras vayas enviando el formulario, si cierras la página la información se pierde. Te recomiendo nuevamente que guardes estos datos en una base de datos y crees el xml consultando la base de datos.

Comment: Gracias @Carrmen! He podido hacerlo usando como base este ejemplo. Me ha costado un poco pero lo he logrado al fin. Una disculpa el tardar tanto tiempo, Pensé que había comentado y olvide hacer. Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: No hay de que, me alegro que te haya servido