# problemas con codificaciones utf8 java en linux

Tags: php, java, linux, ubuntu, java-8

Tengo este problema con java.
Tengo un jar(Es un firmador de xml), este archivo jar lo ejecuto desde php (`shell_exec("java -jar mifirmador.jar")`).
Resulta que cuando lo ejecuto desde windows, me lo firma todo bien. Pero cuando lo ejecuto desde ubunto, es cuando ya no me lo firma bien, el problema son los caracteres, cuando quito las tildes en el xml, ya me funciona bien el firmador en ubunto.

Asi entra al jar en windows

```
<leyenda>
Ley N° 453: Tienes derecho a recibir información sobre las características y contenidos de los servicios que utilices.
</leyenda>
```

Asi sale del jar en windows

```
<leyenda>
Ley NÂ° 453: Tienes derecho a recibir informaciÃ³n sobre las caracterÃ­sticas y contenidos de los servicios que utilices.
</leyenda>
```

Asi entra al jar en ubunto

```
<leyenda>
Ley N° 453: Tienes derecho a recibir información sobre las características y contenidos de los servicios que utilices.
</leyenda>
```

Y asi sale del jar en Ubuntu

```
<leyenda>
Ley N?????? 453: Tienes derecho a recibir informaci??????n sobre las caracter??????sticas y contenidos de los servicios que utilices.
</leyenda>
```

al ejecutar file archivo.xml en windows y ubuntu.

```
En windows -> archivo.xml: UTF-8 Unicode text
En ubuntu   -> archivo.xml: ASCII text
```

**java en windows**

```
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)
```

**java en ubuntu:**

```
java version "1.8.0_301"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_301-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.301-b09, mixed mode)
```

Necesito que este firmador corra en linux ubunto. Ayudaa Porfavor!

Comment: Si tomas el archivo firmado **en güindous** y lo abres en ubuntu, se ve igual? También me gustaría que agarres ambos archivos y les corras `file archivo-guindous.xml archivo-linux.xml` y pongas la salida del comando como información adicional de la pregunta.

Comment: También sería bueno saber cuales son los java que estás usando en ambas ejecuciones (y probablemente también los **encodings** que estás usando).

Comment: Ah... y, por favor, no pongas imágenes en las preguntas. Eso que tienes ahí sería mejor que lo pongas como texto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ok gracias, editare la pregunta. solo que no se como ver los encodings

Comment: @JoseEspinalLuque eso de ver las codificaciones de los archivos suena a una excelente pregunta para este sitio, te recomiendo que lo preguntes en una publicación aparte. PD: por el tipo de caracteres que veo yo creo que usas utf-8

Comment: posiblemente relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83896/error-al-editar-archivo-xml-usando-un-formulario-en-php si te fijas el xml contiene la codificación y creo que podría ser eso tu problema

Comment: Precisamente `file` nos podría decir el encoding.

Comment: El archivo xml lo produce el propio proceso de java o el archivo xml lo produces desde php a partir de salida por stdout de java?

Comment: Lo que hace es: php genera y guarda el xml, y luego java busca ese xml generado por el php y lo firma, Sister.out.println(firmado) así esta la salida de java... PD No se mucho de java

Comment: Por lo que estás describiendo (con el `system.out.println`), el archivo no se construye en java. El _contenido_ del archivo firmado se coloca como salida por stdout en java, así que te apuesto lo que quieras a que el archivo como tal lo construyes con código **en php**. Lo que me hace pensar (aunque puedo estar equivocado) que el problema está en php, no en java. SI le das el mismo archivo de entrada en güindous y en linux, la salida es la misma? Si es así (puede no serlo, por ejemplo, podrían colocar un comentario con la fecha de la ejecucion), podrías hacer md5 a lo que sale de `exec_shell`?

Comment: Lo que creo que sucede es que java en guindous y en linux sacan exactamente lo mismo y es en php que el encoding te está jugando kikiriwiki. Hay varias pruebas que se me ocurre que podrías hacer: `ejecutar java directamente y comparar la salida de ambos en guindous y linux`. Otra es `hacer md5sum no solo en php sino tambien en java para verificar que lo que envías en java es exactamente lo que recibes en php`.

Comment: Tienes que tener mucho cuidado con esta prueba de mirar los md5 en java/php porque estás enviando un salto de línea al final cuando mandas el contenido en java, tendrias que incluirlo al sacar el md5 _en java_ (en php ya estaría en el contenido que se recibe así que no hay que hacer magia).

Comment: Hay otra pregunta grande: `que version de php estás usando en güindous y linux`?

Comment: Tanto en windows linux, php genera el mismo xml, con su codificacion utf8. 
tambien hice prueba con un solo xml en windows y en linux(lo hice correr desde la consola), y el resultado sigue lo mismo, java en windows me bota UFT8, y java en linux me bota ASCII. PD no puedo modificar el archivo jar

Comment: version de php es 7.3 en linux y windows

Comment: Por lo que dices, tendrías que hacer modificaciones del lado de java y si el jar no lo puedes tocar.... pues no es que se pueda hacer mucho. Ahora bien, java utiliza UTF-8 por defecto. En el programa java están haciendo algún tipo de ajuste al encoding?

Comment: El código de java es esta. https://bit.ly/2ZYFvfS a  mi me la pasaron ya compilado, y por lo que veo, esta haciendo un ajuste al encoding utf8 no estoy tan seguro, solo se poco de java